# clEnqueueWriteBuffer writes wrong data into VRAM

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a very curious problem with clEnqueueWriteBuffer. In my current project, I would like to copy ~500 images (1GB) onto the graphics card and average some pixels. The images are stored in one big double* Array (size: width*height*nImages). If I copy 300 images into the VRAM and read it out using clEnqueueReadBuffer,  I get exactly what I had stored in RAM:

RAM: 14450,5006076793 14450,5006076793 14456,8079379383 14455,2294939826 14444,7361060619

VRAM: 14450,5006076793 14450,5006076793 14456,8079379383 14455,2294939826 14444,7361060619

However, if I load more than 350 images, the content of my cl_mem object is corrupt:

RAM:14450,5006076793 14450,5006076793 14456,8079379383 14455,2294939826 14444,7361060619

VRAM:-6,27743856220419E+66 -6,27743856220419E+66 -6,27743856220419E+66 -6,27743856220419E+66 -6,27743856220419E+66

I would be very happy if you could help me out!
Here is my code:

```
private: System::Void button7_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         std::string text;
         text = StringConvA(maskedTextBox1->Text);
         textBox1->Text += "You want a bin size of " + atoi(text.c_str()) + ". You have "+ nforegroundImages+" images.\r\n";
         binWidth = atoi(text.c_str());
         nbins = (int)ceil((double)nforegroundImages / (double)binWidth);
         textBox1->Text += "That is going to give you "+nbins+" bins\r\n";

         //create context and cmd_queue

         context = clCreateContext(NULL, nDevices, &deviceID[0], NULL, NULL, &err);
         cmd_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceID[0], NULL, &err);


         //allocate result memory
         //each result image will have width*height double entries. res_im is an array of pointer to double.


         res_im = (double*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(double)*nbins);


         cl_mem imageData_mem, result_mem, nWavenumber_mem, binSize_mem, imageSizeInPixels_mem, nbins_mem;
         imageData_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, width * height * sizeof(double)*nforegroundImages, NULL, NULL);
         result_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, width * height * sizeof(double)*nbins, NULL, NULL);
         nWavenumber_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
         binSize_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
         imageSizeInPixels_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);
         nbins_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int), NULL, NULL);

         clFinish(cmd_queue);

         int imageSizeInPixels = width*height;
         err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, imageData_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*sizeof(double)*nforegroundImages, (void*)images, 0, NULL, NULL); //this is where the images are copied into VRAM. If nforegroundImages>300, the data in VRAM is wrong, otherwise it is the same as in the images array
         err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, nWavenumber_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)&nforegroundImages, 0, NULL, NULL);
         err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, binSize_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)&binWidth, 0, NULL, NULL);
         err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, imageSizeInPixels_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)&imageSizeInPixels, 0, NULL, NULL);
         err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmd_queue, nbins_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), (void*)&nbins, 0, NULL, NULL);

         clFinish(cmd_queue);

         //read the content of imageData_mem and store it in test array
         double * test = (double*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(double)*nforegroundImages);
         err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmd_queue, imageData_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*sizeof(double)*nforegroundImages,
             test, 0, NULL, NULL);

         clFinish(cmd_queue);

         //compare original value from the images array to the value retrieved from the VRAM
         textBox1->Text += images[1] + "\t" + images[1] + "\t" + images[10] + "\t" + images[100] + "\t" + images[1000] + "\t\r\n"; //original data
         textBox1->Text += test[1] + "\t" + test[1] + "\t" + test[10] + "\t" + test[100] + "\t" + test[1000] + "\t\r\n"; //retrieved from imageData_mem

         free(test);

         //build the program from the source file and print the program build log
         cl_program program[2];
         cl_kernel kernel[2];
         const char * filename = "addKernel.c";
         char *program_source = load_program_source(filename);
         program[0] = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&program_source,
             NULL, &err);
         if (err == CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY){
             textBox1->Text += "Error: out of Host Memory!\r\n";
         }
         else if (err == CL_INVALID_CONTEXT){
             textBox1->Text += "Error: invalid Context!\r\n";
         }
         else if (err == CL_INVALID_VALUE){
             textBox1->Text += "Error: invalid Value!\r\n";
         }



         err = clBuildProgram(program[0], 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
         textBox1->Text += "Program build error: " + err + "\r\n";
         cl_build_status status;
         size_t logSize;
         clGetProgramBuildInfo(program[0], deviceID[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS, sizeof(cl_build_status), &status, NULL);
         clGetProgramBuildInfo(program[0], deviceID[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &logSize);

         char* programLog;
         programLog = (char*)calloc(logSize + 1, sizeof(char));
         clGetProgramBuildInfo(program[0], deviceID[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, logSize + 1, programLog, NULL);
         this->textBox1->Text += "Program build info: error=" + err + ", status=" + status + ", programLog:\r\n" + *programLog + "\r\n" + "In case of an error please make sure that openCL has been initialized\r\n";

         kernel[0] = clCreateKernel(program[0], "filterSpectrum", &err);

         //(__global double *imageData, __global double *result, __constant int *nWavenumbers, __constant int *binSize, __constant int *imageSizeInPixels,__constant int * nbins)
         // Now setup the arguments to our kernel
         err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &imageData_mem);
         err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &result_mem);
         err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &nWavenumber_mem);
         err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &binSize_mem);
         err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 4, sizeof(cl_mem), &imageSizeInPixels_mem);
         err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 5, sizeof(cl_mem), &nbins_mem);

         size_t local_work_size = 32;

         // Run the calculation by enqueuing it and forcing the 
         // command queue to complete the task
         size_t global_work_size = width*height;
         err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmd_queue, kernel[0], 1, NULL,&global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
         clFinish(cmd_queue);

         // Once finished read back the results from the answer 
         // array into the results array
         err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmd_queue, result_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*sizeof(double)*nbins,
             res_im, 0, NULL, NULL);


         clFinish(cmd_queue);
         textBox1->Text += "result values " + res_im[1] + "\t" + res_im[100] + "\t" + res_im[1000] + "\t" + res_im[10000] + "\t" + res_im[100000] + "\t" + res_im[1000000] + "\r\n";

         hScrollBar2->Maximum = nbins+3;

         clReleaseMemObject(imageSizeInPixels_mem);
         clReleaseMemObject(imageData_mem);
         clReleaseMemObject(result_mem);
         clReleaseMemObject(nWavenumber_mem);
         clReleaseMemObject(binSize_mem);
         clReleaseMemObject(nbins_mem);

         clReleaseCommandQueue(cmd_queue);
         clReleaseContext(context);



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely requesting more memory than the driver will allow in a single allocation. It looks like you aren't checking most of the error codes that the OpenCL runtime functions return; doing this makes it *much* easier to diagnose problems with OpenCL programs. You really should do this for *every* API call.

You can find out what the largest single memory allocation your device supports is with the following code snippet:

```
cl_ulong maxMemAlloc;
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, sizeof(cl_ulong), &maxMemAlloc, NULL);
textBox1->Text += "Maximum memory allocation size is " + maxMemAlloc + " bytes\r\n";
```

It's often the case that the largest memory allocation is much less than the total size of the GPU memory. The OpenCL specification only requires that it is at least 1/4 of the maximum size, or at least 128 MB.

Comment: Thank you very much that seems to be my problem: Maximum memory allocation size is 805306368 bytes. I can load a maximum of 326 images which corresponds to 800MB. Do you know if there is any way to increase the maximum memory allocation size? It would be very inconvenient to split up my calculations.

Thank you very much for the suggestion with the error codes. I will keep that in mind for the future ;-)

Comment: Some devices might allow you to do this, but there isn't a portable way. It looks like you may be able to use the `GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT` and `GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE` environment variables on AMD GPUs, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Luckily I have a Radeon 7970. Adjusting the `GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT` to 100 solved my issues

Comment: +1. @mTORjaeger as you have tagged the question C++ I'm surprised that you are not making use of the OpenCL C++ wrapper already. This would alleviate some of the need for error checking (by using exception handling instead) and reduce the snippet above to `textBox1->Text += device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE>()`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am very new to both c++ and opencl (this is my second week working on it) and I am learning it all by myself. There is no one around to tell me those things ;-). Do you know a good tutorial where I can read more about it? As a beginner the Khronos documentation is very cryptic